# No se me hacen espacios entre columnas con bootstrap

Tags: css, grid, bootstrap-5

No se por que pero en la mayoria de paginas al hacer el codigo que dejare, se me crea siempre solo los espacios entre columnas pero en esta pagina que estoy haciendo no se me hace nada, pruebo a darle gx-3 o el offset y nada sigue sin separarse, ya que cuando le das margin baja la columna de al lado.

```
<header class="container bg-inici p-5">
    <div class="row bg-tarjeta"> <!-- ROW GENERAL-->

        <!--1 FILA-->
        <div class="row my-4">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <!--Barcos en venta-->
                    <div class="col-4" >
                        Barcos en Ventas
                    </div>
                    <!--Barcos en alquiler-->
                    <div class="col-8">
                        Barcos en alquiler
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--2 FILA-->
        <div class="row my-4 ">
            <div class="col-12 col-12-header">
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-4 border-line">
                        Estado del Barco
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 border-line">
                        Tipo
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 border-line">
                        Combustible
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--3 FILA-->
        <div class="row my-4">
            <div class="col-12 ">
                <div class="row">                      
                    <div class="col-4 border-line">
                        Precio
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 border-line">
                        Cercania de tu Ubicación
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 border-line">
                        Buscar
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- END DIV ROW GENERAL-->
</header>
```

css

```
.border-line {

background-color: aqua;
padding: 1em;
border-radius: 1em;
text-align:center;
width: 25%;
}

.col-12-header{
background-color: green;
/* margin-left: 6em; */
}

/* HEADER | FILTRO */
.bg-inici {
position: relative;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
color: black;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5em;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), 
url("/img/banner2.png");
}

.bg-tarjeta {    /* Tarjeta barcos */
background-color: var(--first-color);
border-radius: 0.5em;
box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 2px rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.3);
padding: 0em !important;
```

}

[image]

Comment: ¿Bootstrap 4 o 5? Recordá que podés colocar tu código como _snippet_, para que se pueda reproducir el problema en la pregunta misma.

Comment: No se como cargar la libreria de bootstrap con el snipet, es bootstrap 5

Comment: A la izquierda hay un botón que dice _añadir librería externa_: allí podés introducir la URL.

Comment: No tienen porqué separarse, las columnas en Bootstrap siempre van a tratar de ocupar el 100% del ancho asignado según la cantidad mostrada (hasta ocupar 12 columnas por fila). En tu ejemplo, col-4 sólo puede usarse 3 veces por fila (`3 * 4 = 12`), es decir: `100% / 3 = 33.3333%`. Ahora, si necesitas mostrar un espacio, encierra el texto de tus columnas dentro de otro elemento y ese agregarle un padding-x

Comment: Probare, es que hasta ahora aunque ocupase los 12 si se me creaba por defecto el espacio y sino le daba un gx.

Comment: Para poner espacio entre columnas ( con margin ) tienes que meter un div dentro de los col y darle los estilos a ese div

Answer (score 1):

Lo que está mal es la estructura, actualmente bootstrap 5 se cambiaron varias formas de hacer las cosas, aparte de que en el CSS no debes establecer tamaños a menos que sea necesario, trata de usar lo mejor posible el grid de bootstrap, te dejo la solución para la fila 2

```css
.border-line {

background-color: aqua;
padding: 1em;
border-radius: 1em;
text-align:center;
}

.col-12-header{
background-color: green;
/* margin-left: 6em; */
}

/* HEADER | FILTRO */
.bg-inici {
position: relative;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
color: black;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5em;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5em;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), 
url("/img/banner2.png");
}

.bg-tarjeta {    /* Tarjeta barcos */
background-color: var(--first-color);
border-radius: 0.5em;
box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px 2px rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.3);
  padding: 0em !important;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="container bg-inici p-5">
    <div class="row bg-tarjeta"> <!-- ROW GENERAL-->

        <!--1 FILA-->
        <div class="row my-4">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <!--Barcos en venta-->
                    <div class="col-4" >
                        Barcos en Ventas
                    </div>
                    <!--Barcos en alquiler-->
                    <div class="col-8">
                        Barcos en alquiler
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--2 FILA-->
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-12 col-12-header">
                   <div class="row row-cols-lg-3">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="border-line">Estado del Barco</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="border-line">Tipo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="border-line">Combustible</div>
    </div>
 </div>
  </div>
      </div>     
          
        </div>
        <!--3 FILA-->
        <div class="row my-4">
            <div class="col-12 ">
                <div class="row">                      
                    <div class="col-4 border-line">
                        Precio
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 border-line">
                        Cercania de tu Ubicación
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 border-line">
                        Buscar
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- END DIV ROW GENERAL-->
</header>
```

desde la documentación: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/

Comment: entiendo, lo del `row-cols-`que significa eso de cols es la primera vez que le veo

Comment: Como te comentaba es una función nueva que básicamente establece desde el row cuantas columnas va a tener el div en lugar de hacer <div class="row"><div class="col-6"></div><div class="col-6"></div></row> ahora simplemente se hace: <div class="row row-cols-2"><div class="col"></div><div class="col"></div></row> que establece que dentro del row hay 2 columnas, si te recomiendo leer toda la documentación porque si agregaron y modificaron bastantes cosas, a mi tambien me costo un poco entenderlo al principio